# How to pass line item names without saving in inventory in quickbooks API PHP

Tags: php, api, quickbooks

I am using Quickbooks V3 by following this package. https://github.com/consolibyte/quickbooks-php

Is it possible to add line item to invoice  without creating it in inventory/non-inventory?

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to add line item to invoice without creating it in inventory/non-inventory?

No.

QuickBooks requires that you associate each line item on an invoice to an item/service/product.